# JQuery AJAX is encoding API Token for Laravel Application, results in 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a small application and it has one route that returns JSON. If I use Postman or my browser, I get the correct result. Similarly, if I am running a server on my computer, I get the correct result.

On a live server, however, jQuery is encoding the api token before submitting it, and I'm not getting the result, just a 401 error.

```
let product_id = $(this).val()
let token   = $('input[name=token]').val()

$.ajax({
  url: 'api/campaign/',
  data: {
    'product_id': product_id,
    'api_token': token,
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // Do Stuff
  }
})
```

Comment: @dana it is a `bcrypt` string.

Comment: if sending as post in postman need to set `method` as `post` for ajax